# Python Template Variables not recognised in IDE (Pycharm)

Tags: python, flask

New to Python Flask and trying to work out some ideas I have learned.

I am working with Pycharm but it seems that template variables and template tags (such as {% for %}) are not recognised.

My goal is to pass some data into the HTML file and iterate through a list variable.

Already tried to install different packages such as Django, Jinja2 and more. But no luck.

Code Below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "Key"

my_list = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', my_list=my_list)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>My List<h1>
    {% for items in my_list %}
        <li>items</li>
    {% endfor % }
        
</body>
</html>
```

Also note my import statements. Maybe i missed one?

Hope all clear.

Cheers
Kenny.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `{{ ... }}` expression in Jinja to get the variable output.

Change `<li>items</li>` to `<li>{{ items }}</li>` in your Jinja `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot those will in the code above. But same output when i add them: Outpot to local host: 
{% for items in my_list %}
{{ items }}
{% endfor % }

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is the issue? Is the for loop not executing in your template or what happens, do you receive an error?

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine except there is extra space on `{% endfor % }` which causes `TemplateSyntaxError`, it should be `{% endfor %}` instead.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. Code get executed but data (my_list) is not shown in the local host (HTML). It literally shows:  {% for items in my_list %} {{ items }} {% endfor % }.  While i expect it to show:  My List (as header) and the data in bullet points only.